# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC : Selectbox that shows categories from the database table returns null when creating an idea

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a select box which retrieves all categories using a repository but when creating an idea, the selected category returns null.

These are my model classes:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Idea
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Rating { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category? Category { get; set; }
    public  IEnumerable<Category>? Categories { get; set; }
}
```

This is the home controller for when I have to create an idea, as soon I click the create icon, the select box that retrieves all categories, gets the category Id and passes it to the `CategoryId` (foreign key in the idea model) but it can't link it to the actual id in the category table, such that when displaying items like `@model Idea.Category.Name` it returns a null

```
[HttpPost
public async Task<IActionResult> AddIdea(Idea viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var idea = new Idea
                       {
                           Name = viewModel.Name,
                           Description = viewModel.Description,
                           Rating = viewModel.Rating,
                           Status = viewModel.Status,
                           Date = viewModel.Date,
                           CategoryId = viewModel.CategoryId, 
                           Category = viewModel.Category,  // this is where it says null, without it the modelState becomes false.
                       };

        _ideaRepository.Add(idea);

        // Redirect to home or any other page
        return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
    }

    var categories = await _categoryRepository.GetAllCategories();
    ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(categories, "Id", "Name");

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add code and data as text [(using code formatting)](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#duplicate=0), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; C) are difficult to read clearly by visual impaired user and other reasons explained in detail here. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like below, the issue could be fixed. You should get `category` from database first, because in add new model page, the category is null. And I saw you have categoryId, so you could get `category`, so please using my code to fix the issue.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddIdea(Idea viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Get category and use it
        var category = await _categoryRepository.GetCategoryById(viewModel.CategoryId);

        var idea = new Idea
                       {
                           Name = viewModel.Name,
                           Description = viewModel.Description,
                           Rating = viewModel.Rating,
                           Status = viewModel.Status,
                           Date = viewModel.Date,
                           CategoryId = viewModel.CategoryId, 
                           //Category = viewModel.Category,  // this is where it says null, without it the modelState becomes false.
                           // Use category, it will not null
                           Category = category;
                       };

        _ideaRepository.Add(idea);

        // Redirect to home or any other page
        return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
    }

    var categories = await _categoryRepository.GetAllCategories();
    ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(categories, "Id", "Name");

    return View(viewModel);
}
```